# Send wrong values to the next activity in search

Tags: android, listview, search, android-activity, import

i have problem with search, when user type something, listview will change, so the next activity will recive wrong values.
my code:

```
    package com.example.finaltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;

public class Search extends ActionBarActivity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.search);

                // Listview Data
        String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.search);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.subject_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
                Search.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
            }
        });

        // after click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                int position, long id) {

                final String item = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                int total_number = 50;
                for(int x = 1; x < total_number+1; x = x+1) {
                        String SubjectName = "subject_" + String.valueOf(x);
                        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(SubjectName, "string", getPackageName());
                        String subject = getResources().getString(resID);

                        if(item.equals(subject)) {
                                String StringClass = "com.example.finaltest.Subject_" + String.valueOf(x);
                                Class<?> c = null;
                                if(StringClass != null) {
                                    try {
                                        c = Class.forName(StringClass);
                                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Show_Subjects.class);
                                String Subject_number = String.valueOf(position+1);
                                i.putExtra("subject_number", Subject_number);
                                startActivity(i); 
                        }
                }

            }

          });
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    Intent delIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Settings.class);
                    Search.this.startActivity(delIntent);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_favorites:
                    Intent delItemIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Favorites.class);
                    Search.this.startActivity(delItemIntent);
                    return true;
            }
            return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

my string names are Subject_N , i want to send values of N to next activity(from item row number)

my language is persian ,also i have an other problem, search field only support english ! change language is Inactive

Comment: hi first of all x=x+1 and x++ meaning are same by convention we wrote the latter one mostly while using for loop moreover, if you can provide details like what is the current output and what is the expected one than it can be more easy  to help you

Comment: my string names are Subject_N , i want to send values of N to next activity

Comment: from item row number

Answer (score 0):

```
//outside the for loop
ArrayList<String> ArraySubject_number = new ArrayList<String>();
String Subject_number;

//initialize your arraylist inside the loop for each row
//use something like
//for each row
Subject_number = String.valueOf(position+1);
ArraySubject_number.add(Subject_number);  

//outside for loop
Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Show_Subjects.class);
intent.putExtras("subject_number", ArraySubject_number);
```

then in your other activity use this code to access them

```
ArrayList<String> ArraySubject_number = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("subject_number");
```

Comment: can you give me full code pls?! i don`t have problem with get values in next activity, just give full search code pls. tnx

Comment: i can make one for you,if you can give me some details like what you want the code to do  terms of functionality

Comment: i want to show search in listview, my list view must show my string with name Subject_N in string.xml, and send position(item row) befor changing after search to next activity. for ex. Subject_6 is In the sixth row at the first (befor user do search), but after search it will be In the first row, i need to send i=6 to next activity. i have 50strings, and i use a class with name Globals to define subject_total_number(50)

Comment: also i can don`t show the listview, just search in my string with name Subject_N, and send N values to next activity